# reducing MASSIVE amounts of child elements

Tags: jquery, html, nested, children

I'm using a lot of parent div containers with 100 child elements, some even have 500 children.

```
<div id="px">
<div> icon1 </div>
<div> icon2 </div>
... +98
</div>

<div id="content">
<div> images, text.. etc </div>
<div> images, text.. etc </div>
... +98
</div>
```

The reason I'm doing that is so I can specify a mouseenter event to each child element with 1 single jquery code, and then show some content based on that child selection:

```
$("#px >").mouseenter(function() {

index = (this).index();    

$("#content :eq("+index+")").css("display","block"); });
```

Is there any better way of doing this or reduce the markup/css needed for this? Because my html and css is going to be ridiculously long and probably perform horrible.

Comment: Is there actually a performance issue? If you *need* visible distinct elements, then you *need* visible distinct elements. While there may be a case to use Canvas or even SVG here, that ultimately changes the entire display and interaction. Alternatively, perhaps only a subset of the data should be displayed (i.e. even created) at any time ..

Comment: It's only "too big" if there is an unacceptable performance problem - I'd expect a modern desktop browser to be able to handle many thousands of nodes; there are over 1k+ on this simple page alone. Anyway, the data has to be somewhere. Dynamically creating the (displayed) DOM from a JavaScript object or XHR request (which is really just a form of "paging") is one approach ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can change the markup being generated, I would suggest rendering the markup with data attributes as below:

```
<div id="px">
<div class="icon" data-target="icon1-tgt"> icon1 </div>
<div class="icon" data-target="icon2-tgt"> icon2 </div>
... +98
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="icon1-tgt"> images, text.. etc </div>
<div id="icon2-tgt"> images, text.. etc </div>
... +98
</div>
```

and change the js handler to the version below:
Notice that I have used the `on` for event binding, it reduces number of event listeners bound. Check "Event Delegation" section of http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/

```
$("#px").on("mouseenter", "div.icon", function(evt) {
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $("#" + target).css("display","block"); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to find a way not to use so many child elements. I'm worried about the size/performance of the html, if it contains around 1200 child elements, all with different styles. Is there any way of having less elements in the containers?

Comment: @user3121103 Let me ask you, why do you want to display 1200 elements on a page and assign a behavior to each element? Without insight into what needs to achieved, its tough for me to provide any further inputs.

Comment: @user3121103 Hmmm... I cannot think of any other approach to what you are trying to achieve ...

Comment: I just need to reduce the child elements. Maybe I should use json or xml to store all the content, and then retrieve it?